# How do I calculate how often I have to buy two items to craft the max amount?

Tags: java, algorithm, minecraft

I want to to make an algorithm, which calculates the amount of clicks needed to fill an minecraft inventory as far as possible with two different items to craft the max amount of times following some rules.
Most items have max stacks of 64, but in my function I use ender pearls with max stack size 16 and blaze rods, which first have to be made to blaze powder, by which the amount doubles. Every "click" /"buy" for an item gives 64 of it, indepentently of the max stack size.
The items are used for a crafting recipe. The aim is to craft this crafting recipe as often as possible with the given space of the inventory (max 36).

This is what I came up with so far. The function is not properly working:

```
public static int[] calcAmount(int item1, int stacksize1, int item2, int stacksize2, int invSlots){
        int invSpace = invSlots * 64;
        int oneCraft = 0;
        oneCraft = invSpace / ((item1 * (64 / stacksize1)) + (item2 * (64 / stacksize2)));

        float clicks1 = oneCraft * ((float) item1 / stacksize1);
        float clicks2 = oneCraft * ((float) item2 / stacksize2);

    return new int[] {(int)clicks1, (int)clicks2};
    }
```

The two integers item1 and item2 are the amounts needed to craft one time. (e.g. 128, 32)
The integers stacksizes are the max stacksizes for a given item. (e.g. I need 32 ender pearls for crafting once, max stack size is 16. So it needs two inventory space but only half a click.
For an item like the blaze rod I introduced stacksize 32. It actually stacks until 64, but I need the same space as there is blaze rod space left to craft it to blaze powder, by which it doubles in amount.
Example Input:

```
calcAmount(32, 16, 128, 32, 36)
-> out: [12, 24]
expected: [4, 8]
```

I hope this is understandable! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please add specific example. Input, expected output, output (and also debugging information)

Comment: Quick advice, I recommend using double instead of float. Float has its place, but unless you know you need it, default to choosing double. It's more precise.